# Gauss map differential codomain

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I have a simple doubt coming from this Do Carmo's Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces extract:

[image]

Why are $T_p(S)$ and $T_{N(p)}(S^2)$ the same vector spaces? I suppose it's something easy and straightforward to show but I've been thinking about it for a while and I don't find a rigurous way of proving it.

Comment: What is the tangent plane $T_q(S^2)$?